# Shell script to replace string in multiple files within selected directories

Tags: files, scripting

I created the script below which takes the path of a single directory and replaces search string in all the files within that directory. I would like to enhance this script in such a way that it can search and replace the string in multiple directories which are listed in an external input file.

External input file content:

```
/var/start/system1/dir1
/var/start/system2/dir2
/var/start/system3/dir3
/var/start/system4/dir4
```

Script with one directory:

```
filepath="/var/start/system/dir1"
searchstring="test"
replacestring="test01"

i=0; 

for file in $(grep -l -R $searchstring $filepath)
do
  cp $file $file.bak
  sed -e "s/$searchstring/$replacestring/ig" $file > tempfile.tmp
  mv tempfile.tmp $file

  let i++;

  echo "Modified: " $file
done
```

Comment: Your code makes the implicit assumption that none of the paths to be replaced in contain spaces. Is this something that solutions can rely on?

Comment: Path has not spaces ,example below : 
/var/start/system1/dir1 
/var/start/system1/dir2
/var/start/system1/dir3

Answer (score 3):

First of all, the tmpfile dance can be avoided by using `sed -i` with GNU `sed` or `sed -i ''` with FreeBSD's (in-place replacement).

`grep -R` can take multiple paths on the command line, so if you are confident that none of the paths contain spaces, you can replace `$(grep -l -Re "$searchstring" "$filepath")` with `$(grep -l -R "$searchstring" $(cat path_list))`.

This will fail if any of the paths contain spaces, tabs, or any globbing character, but so will the original.

A much more robust approach uses `find` and just applies sed to all of the files, trusting it not to modify files with no matches (here assuming a `bash` shell):

```
# Read newline-separated path list into array from file 'path_list'
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a paths path_list

# Run sed on everything
find "${paths[@]}" \
  -exec sed -i -r -e "s/$searchstring/$replacestring/ig" '{}' ';'
```

But this doesn't give you any feedback on which files it's modifying.

A lengthier version that does give you the feedback:

```
# Read newline-separated path list into array from file 'path_list'
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a paths path_list

grep -l -R "$searchstring" "${paths[@]}" | while IFS= read -r file; do
  sed -r -i -e "s/$searchstring/$replacestring/ig" "$file"
  echo "Modified: $file"
done
```

Comment: You're not avoiding tmp files with `-i` - GNU `sed` creates tmp files with `-i` when you use it.

Comment: What you're avoiding is manually wrangling tmp files yourself.

Comment: I created "path_list" file with the list of directories(mentioned below) in the same directory where the script is located .When I executed the script, it is halting after the IFS step and is not proceeding further.Am I missing something here?


"path_list" file content:

/home/sap1/scrp/directory1
/home/sap/scrp1/directory2
/home/sap/scrp2/directory3


Script used:

path_list=/home/oracon/scrp
cd ${path_list}

IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a paths path_list

grep -l -R "$AP44" "${paths[@]}" | while IFS= read -r file; do
  sed -r -i -e "s/$AP44/$AP45/ig" "$file"
  echo "Modified: $file"
done

Comment: @Toxicfrog - agreed - though I probably don't avoid them, shell depending. I just realized I misspelled your username. Sorry.

Comment: @ToxixFeog - I tried below and the script does nothing. am i missing something here ?

path_list file:
file content: 
/home/sap1/scrp/directory1 
/home/sap/scrp1/directory2 
/home/sap/scrp2/directory3 

Script used: 
path_list=/home/oracon/scrp 
cd ${path_list} 
IFS=$'\n' read -d '' -r -a paths path_list 
grep -l -R "$AP44" "${paths[@]}" | while IFS= read -r file; do sed -r -i -e "s/$AP44/$AP45/ig" "$file" 
echo "Modified: $file" 

done

Answer (score 3):

With GNU tools

```
< dir.list xargs -rd '\n' grep -rlZ -- "$searchstring" |
  xargs -r0 sed -i -e "s/$searchstring/$replacestring/ig" --
```

(Don't forget to quote your variables, leaving a variable unquoted is the split+glob operator)

Comment: I tried below and doesn't seems to be working. am i missing something here ? </home/sap1/scrp/directory2 xargs -rd '\n' grep -rlZ -- "$AP44" | xargs -r0 sed -ie "s/$AP44/$Ap45/ig"

Comment: @user68775, sorry, it should  have been `-i -e`. `-i` takes an optional argument and here `-ie` was taken as `e` being the argument to `-i`.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most portable way I can think to do this, though it still relies on the *mostly* portable `/dev/fd/0` for `.dot`. Without it though, you could use a single file. In any case, it mostly relies on this shell function I wrote the other day:

```
_sed_cesc_qt() { 
    sed -n ':n;\|^'"$1"'|!{H;$!{n;bn}};{$l;x;l}' |
    sed -n '\|^'"$1"'|{:n;\|[$]$|!{
            N;s|.\n||;bn};s|||
            \|\([^\\]\)\\\([0-9]\)|{
            s||\1\\0\2|g;}'"
            s|'"'|&"&"&|g;'"s|.*|'&'|p}"

}
```

First I'll show it work, then I'll explain how. So, I'll create a test file base:

```
printf 'f=%d
    echo "$f" >./"$f"
    echo "$f" >./"$f\n$f"
    echo "$f" >./"$f\n$f\n$f"
' $(seq 10) | . /dev/fd/0
```

That creates a bunch of files, each named for the number 1-10 that it contains:

```
ls -qm 
1, 1?1, 1?1?1, 10, 10?10, 10?10?10, 2, 2?2, 2?2?2, 3, 3?3, 3?3?3, 4, 4?4, 4?4?4, 5, 5?5, 5?5?5, 6, 6?6, 6?6?6, 7,
7?7, 7?7?7, 8, 8?8, 8?8?8, 9, 9?9, 9?9?9
```

That's a comma-delimited list of the files in my test directory, each `?` representing a newline.

```
cat ./1*

1
1
1
10
10
10
```

Each file contains only a single number.

Now I'll do the `grep` replace:

```
find ././ \! -type d -exec \
        grep -l '[02468]$' \{\} + |
_sed_cesc_qt '\./\./' | 
sed 's|.|\\&|g' |
xargs printf 'f=%b
        sed "/[02468]\\$/s//CHANGED/" <<-SED >"$f"
        $(cat <"$f")
        SED\n' | 
. /dev/fd/0
```

Now when I...

```
cat ./1*

1
1
1
1CHANGED
1CHANGED
1CHANGED
```

All of the `[2468]` files are similarly `CHANGED`. It works recursively as well. Ok, so now I'll explain how.

First, I guess, the function:

1. start at `:n`ext label
2. `\|`address`|` argument `$1` - a marker
3. if current line is `!`not a match `{`

   - append it to `H`old buffer
   - if current line is `!`not `$`last line `{`
   - overwrite current line with `n`ext line
   - `b`ranch back to `:n`ext label
   - `}}`
4. else if current line is `$`last line `l`ook at pattern space
5. else e`x`change contents of hold and pattern buffers and...
6. `l`ook unequivocally at pattern space

That's the first `sed` statement - and it's pretty much the meat and potatoes of it. We never `p`rint the pattern space at all - we only `l`ook at it. This is how POSIX defines the `l` function:

> [2addr] `l` *(The letter ell.)* Write the pattern space to standard output
>   in a visually unambiguous form. The characters listed in the Base
>   Definitions volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001, Table 5-1, Escape
>   Sequences and Associated Actions `( '\\', '\a', '\b', '\f', '\r', '\t', '\v' )` shall be written as the corresponding escape sequence; the `'\n'`
>   in that table is not applicable. Non-printable characters not in that
>   table shall be written as one *three-digit* octal number (with a
>   preceding `\`backslash) for each byte in the character (most significant
>   byte first). Long lines shall be folded, with the point of folding
>   indicated by writing a `\`backslash followed by a `\n`ewline; the length
>   at which folding occurs is unspecified, but should be appropriate for
>   the output device. The end of each line shall be marked with a `'$'`.

So if I do:

```
printf '\e%s10\n10\n10' '\' | sed -n 'N;N;l'
```

I get:

```
\033\\10\n10\n10$
```

That's almost perfectly escaped for `printf`. It needs only an extra zero for the octal and to remove the trailing `$` - so the next `sed` statement cleans it up.

I'm not going to do the same level of detail, but basically the next `sed` statement:

1. If line begins with `$1` marker...
2. Pulls in the `N`ext line until the current line ends in `$`
3. If it had to do the above, it removes the trailing `\`backslash and `\n`ewline character.
4. Then it removes the trailing `$`
5. finds any `\`backslashes followed by a number that are not preceded by another `\`backslash and inserts a zero
6. Searches out any `'`single quotes and double-quotes them
7. Finally it surrounds the entire string with `'`single-quotes

So now, when I do:

```
printf %s\\n ././1* |
_sed_cesc_qt '\./\./'
```

I get:

```
'././1'
'././1\n1'
'././1\n1\n1'
'././10'
'././10\n10'
'././10\n10\n10'
```

The rest is kind of easy. It depends on the fact that the `././` string will resolve, but it will only occur in `find/grep`'s output at the head of every path name - so it becomes my `$1` marker.

I `-exec grep` from `find` and specify `-l` for it to output filenames for those files that contain the regex.

I call the function and get its output.

I then `\`backslash escape every character in its output for `xargs`.

And with `printf` I write a script to the `|pipe` file - which I `.dot` source as `/dev/fd/0`. I define the `f` variable as its current argument - my pathname - and `cat` that `$f` argument to a `<<`heredocument, which is fed to `sed`, and `sed` writes back over the source file.

This may involve temporary files - that depends on your shell. `bash` and `zsh` will write out a temporary file for every heredocument - but they clean them up, too. `dash`, on the other hand, will just write the heredocument to an anonymous `|pipe`.

The important thing about it though is that the file will have to be fully read before its written over - it's just how heredocuments and command substitution work.